# Is there a way to create an alias/variable/command to repeat a static code block in Cypress Tests?

Tags: frontend, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm testing a very long form page which has 12 input fields. I'm basically testing the autosaving feature of the form page. So the test logic is to visit each field, type a value, then check if the header has the `saving` and `saved` status message. Then reload the page and see if the input field is retaining its value. For eg.

```
// Aliases for the input fields
cy.get('div[name="title"] input').as('Title');
cy.get('div[name="location"] input').as('Location');
cy.get('div[name="duration"] input').as('Duration');
....


cy.get('@Title').type(randomTitle);


// @Testing save status and reload -------------------
cy.get('.form-header').within(() => {
  cy.contains('SAVING');
  cy.contains('SAVED');
});
cy.reload();
//----------------------------------------------------


cy.get('@Title').then((elem) => {
  expect(elem.val()).to.equal(randomTitle);
});
```

Everything is working fine, however I was hoping if I could refactor the code to make it more cleaner. Only problem I see is I'm essentially repeating the `@Testing save status and reload` code block 12 times. Is there anyway in Cypress I can create an alias, variable or command to run that particular block with a one liner? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm such an idiot, the answer to this question is in the title itself.
All i had to do was create a command like this, in commands file.

```
const checkSaveStatus = () => {
cy.get('.form-header').within(() => {
  cy.contains('SAVING');
  cy.contains('SAVED');
});
cy.reload();
};
Cypress.Commands.add('checkSaveStatus', checkSaveStatus);
```

And call it in my tests like this

```
cy.checkSaveStatus();
```